# ¿Como seleccionar varios registros con Checkbox?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, pdo

Estoy haciendo un facturero, y a la hora de facturar varios productos se me ocurrió usar `checkboxs` ya que aun no me he metido con `JS`, así esta el código de los `checkboxs`:

```
<?php
require_once ("ModeloProductos.php");
$consulta = new Productos();
foreach ($consulta->mostrar_productos() as $registro):?>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $registro->Codigo?></td>
    <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $registro->producto?></td>
    <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $registro->precio . " BsF "?></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name ='codigo[]' value='<?php echo $registro->Codigo?>'></td>
    <input type="hidden" value="24" name="acceso">
</tr>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

Cada `checkbox` tendrá el código de ese producto, el problema pasa cuando selecciono mas de 1, paso todo el arreglo, lo recorro con la sentencia y solo me devuelve el ultimo `checkbox` seleccionado y no los demás, aquí el código:

```
$arreglo = $_POST["codigo"];
$cantidad = count($arreglo);

require_once ("Conexion.php");

$conexion = Conexion::conectar();

for ($i = 0 ; $i < $cantidad ; $i++)
{
    $consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT producto, precio FROM productos WHERE Codigo = $arreglo[$i]");
    $consulta->execute();
    $registro = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

foreach ($registro as $item)
{
    echo $item->producto;
    echo $item->precio;
}
```

Ahí en teoría lo que estaría haciendo es un ciclo para ir realizando la consulta, en donde seleccionaría el producto y el precio en donde el código fuera igual al código en esa posición, pero solo me toma el ultimo `checkbox` seleccionado.

Un ejemplo mas claro para que me entiendan mejor: tengo tres `checkbox`, un código cada uno, selecciono los tres, a la hora de facturar me debería devolver el producto y el precio de esos tres `checkboxs` seleccionados, pero solamente me devuelve el del ultimo `checkbox`.

Answer (score 4):

Como aparentemente estás usando `PDO` para acceder a la base de datos, hay un par de cositas a corregir (además del problema de la pregunta original):

1) No tiene sentido usar `prepare` dentro de un ciclo, se debe ejecutar fuera de él.

2) Al usar `prepare` es incorrecto concatenar una variable dentro del string de la consulta. Se deben usar placeholders.

3) Luego, dentro del ciclo `for` ejecutar la consulta preparada asignando el valor al placeholder.

4) Si el campo `codigo` es único por cada checkbox (supongo que será clave de la tabla) no es necesario usar `fetchAll` ya que nunca traerás más de un registro, con `fetch` alcanza.

5) Y ahora sí, resolviendo el tema de la pregunta, deberías declarar la variable `$registros` fuera del ciclo como un array y dentro de éste ir cargando cada objeto obtenido con la consulta.

```
$consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT producto, precio FROM productos WHERE Codigo = :CODIGO");

$registros = array();

for ($i = 0 ; $i < $cantidad ; $i++) {
    $consulta->execute(array(
        ':CODIGO' => $arreglo[$i]
    ));
    $registros[] = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

// $registros es un array de objetos:
foreach ($registros as $item) {
    echo $item->producto;
    echo $item->precio;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

la solución es muy sencilla, el problema solo es que en el for estas sobrescribiendo los valores de los productos en la variable $registro:

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $cantidad ; $i++) {

    $consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT producto, precio FROM productos WHERE Codigo = $arreglo[$i]");
    $consulta->execute();
    $registro = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); //<=aqui
}
```

Es por eso que te salen solo los valores del ultimo registro, cuando lo correcto es que deberías declarar el array $registro y colocar los valores de los productos como si fuera un vector:

```
$registro=array(); //declarar el array 

for ($i = 0 ; $i < $cantidad ; $i++) {

    $consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT producto, precio FROM productos WHERE Codigo = $arreglo[$i]");
    $consulta->execute();
    $registro[$i] = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); //<=aqui te falta el [i]
}
```

De esta forma ya tienes todos los registros para hacer el foreach. Espero que te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creeria que tu error esta en la variable $registro ya que no esta declarada fuera del for, bueno ese es el primero el segundo es que cada vez que se ejecuta el ciclo for la misma variable $registro se reescribe es decir borra el anterior objeto para crear el nuevo, intenta probar este código:

```
$arreglo = $_POST["codigo"];
$cantidad = count($arreglo);

require_once ("Conexion.php");

$conexion = Conexion::conectar();
$registro = array();

for ($i = 0 ; $i < $cantidad ; $i++) {

    $consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT producto, precio FROM productos WHERE Codigo = $arreglo[$i]");
    $consulta->execute();
    array_push($registro,$consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
}

foreach ($registro as $item) {

    echo $item->producto;
    echo $item->precio;
}
```

Lo que hace es que inicializa la variable $registro como un array luego en el ciclo for solo añadimos los nuevos objetos.

Comment: por favor mira [answer] y de paso haz el [tour]. Gracias por la respuesta!